# Is there a way to ask Hudson to skip the scm poll during a build?

Tags: svn, hudson

I have configured a job in hudson that's linked to an SCM, is there a way for me to get hudson to not poll the scm before starting the build? I'd like to ideally not have to create a separate job for this.

Thanks!

- Dinesh.

Comment: What is you intend behind that job. I somehow can not come up with a good example, for having a dependency on a change without actually downloading the change.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off "Poll SCM" checkbox in the area "Build Triggers". This should it be.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to trigger a build on commit, but without polling; if this is the case, you can configure a post-commit hook to call a URL (works for CVS or SVN, not sure about other SCMs).  The Hudson wiki has some information about this [here](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-BuildsbychangesinSubversion%2FCVS).